# When do bounds for eigenvalues become strict?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ be a real square matrix with eigenvalues $\lambda_k(A), \, k=1, \dots, n$. Further, let $S = (A+A^T)/2$ denote the symmetric part of $A$. [Bendixson](http://link.springer.com.e.bibl.liu.se/article/10.1007%2FBF02419030) (1902) showed that
$$
\min_j \lambda_j(S) \leq \Re{[\lambda_k(A)]} \leq \max_j \lambda_j(S), \quad k=1, \dots, n
$$
i.e. the real part of the eigenvalues of $A$ are bounded from below and above by the smallest and largest eigenvalues of $S$ respectively.

Under what circumstances can these inequalities be made strict? Are there any necessary or sufficient conditions on $A$ that would guarantee that equality cannot hold?

Answer (score 0):

One case where there is an equality is when $A$ is a normal matrix, that is $A A^T = A^T A$.

If $A$ is normal it implies that the antisymmetric part of $A$, $T = (A - A^T)/2$, commutes with its symmetric part $S T = T S$. Hence, we can simultaneously diagonalize $S$ and $T$. The eigenvalues of $A$ are
$$\lambda_j(A) = \lambda_j(S) + i\lambda_j(T), \quad j = 1, \cdots, n.$$

In a few words, in this case, the real part of the eigenvalues of $A$ is $S$.

So, a necessary, but not yet sufficient, condition for the equality not to hold, is that $A$ is not normal.