# Bounds on real parts of eigenvalues for non-nonnegative real matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Does anyone know bounds on the real parts of eigenvalues for generic real matrices? In particular I have a real matrix with complex eigenvalues with negative real parts, and I am looking for a bound on the maximum of the real parts (minimum absolute value) of the eigenvalues (to estimate the speed of convergence of a dynamical system).

In particular, is there any generalization of results like the following ones:

-For nonnegative irreducible matrices $A$ there is the following bound on the largest eigenvalue $\lambda_1$: $$ \min \sum_{j}A_{ij} \le\lambda_1\le\max \sum_{j}A_{ij} $$

-For real matrices and real eigenvalues, from Gershgorin circle theorem it follows that:
$$|\lambda|\le \max \sum_{j}|A_{ij}| $$

Comment: I suspect that you could get somewhere by looking at the eigenvalues of $A + A^T$. In particular: if $A + A^T$ is (symmetric and) negative definite, then we can guarantee that $A$ has eigenvalues with negative real parts and I think that we can bound those real parts using the eigenvalues of $A + A^T$.

Comment: Also, the Gershgorin circle theorem will work if $A$ is diagonally dominant

Comment: Yes, there is a result cited here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/271868/relation-between-real-part-of-eigenvalues-of-a-and-aat-2 saying that the real parts are bounded between the minimum and maximum eigenvalue of $A+A^t$. Unfortunately such a bound is too lose for me

Comment: As far as I understand the Gershgorin circle theorem per se applies to any matrix https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem, if the matrix is diagonally dominant then it is particularly useful because one can then conclude that the eigenvalues are all positive (or negative)

Comment: "Matrix measure" or Logarithmic norm (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_norm) might be useful for you. In particular, if you select 2-norm the convergence rate is $\lambda_{\operatorname{max}}\left( \frac{A+A^T}{2} \right)$. But other norm selections might work better for specific cases.

Answer (score 0):

In general I think that [Bendixson's bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bendixson%27s_inequality), which you mention in one of your comments, is the best one can do, without further constraints on $A$ or its antisymmetric part $K = (A - A^T)/2$.

The reason being that if $\lambda_1(S)$ is the largest eigenvalue of $S = (A + A^T)/2$, then $\text{Re}\{\lambda_1\}(A) \leq \lambda_1(S)$. If $A$ is normal, $A A^T = A^T A$, then it becomes an [equality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1872843/when-do-bounds-for-eigenvalues-become-strict/4853725#4853725).

So, if it is not possible to compute $\lambda_1(S)$ explicitly, one option is to use bounds on the $\lambda_1(S)$, like Gershgorin circle theorem, or [Laguerre/Samuelson bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometrical_properties_of_polynomial_roots#Polynomials_whose_roots_are_all_real), on $\lambda_1(S)$. However, they most likely will be less strict than Bendixson's bound.

Otherwise, you make $A$ traceless $\tilde{A} = A - \frac{\text{Tr}A}{n}I$ and look for bounds on its largest positive root $\lambda_1(\tilde{A})$ from the [coefficients of the characteristic polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometrical_properties_of_polynomial_roots#Bounds_of_real_roots). Then, translate that bound back to $\lambda_1(A)$.

If the bound from the characteristic polynomial are tighter than Bendixson's bound, its because you have incorporated information about the antisymmetric part of $A$, when computing the characteristic polynomial.